# Geopandas geoseries area - units?

Tags: gis, geopandas

I have a GeoPandas DataFrame. I apply a couple of functions to the GeoDataFrame.

1. Buffer - https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.buffer.html

This creates a set of points around the coordinates / geometry.

```py
import geopandas
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, Polygon

s = geopandas.GeoSeries(
    [
        Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)]),
        Polygon([(10, 0), (10, 5), (0, 0)]),
        Polygon([(0, 0), (2, 2), (2, 0)]),
        LineString([(0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)]),
        Point(0, 1)
    ]
)

s.buffer(0.2)
```

2. Now, I'd like to measure the area of the buffered geometry using: https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.area.html

   `s.area`

The `crs` info of the DataFrame is:

```
<Derived Projected CRS: ESRI:102003>
Name: USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic
Axis Info [cartesian]:
- E[east]: Easting (metre)
- N[north]: Northing (metre)
Area of Use:
- name: United States (USA) - CONUS onshore - Alabama; Arizona; Arkansas; California; Colorado; Connecticut; Delaware; Florida; Georgia; Idaho; Illinois; Indiana; Iowa; Kansas; Kentucky; Louisiana; Maine; Maryland; Massachusetts; Michigan; Minnesota; Mississippi; Missouri; Montana; Nebraska; Nevada; New Hampshire; New Jersey; New Mexico; New York; North Carolina; North Dakota; Ohio; Oklahoma; Oregon; Pennsylvania; Rhode Island; South Carolina; South Dakota; Tennessee; Texas; Utah; Vermont; Virginia; Washington; West Virginia; Wisconsin; Wyoming.
- bounds: (-124.79, 24.41, -66.91, 49.38)
Coordinate Operation:
- name: USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic
- method: Albers Equal Area
Datum: North American Datum 1983
- Ellipsoid: GRS 1980
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
```

My question is: what is the units of the area calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The units of area would be `metre^2`. The units are reported in the CRS.

Presumably, the actual shapefile has very large values (e.g. in the ~1e6 range). See e.g. this question: [Interpreting GeoPandas Polygon coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72347493/interpreting-geopandas-polygon-coordinates/72354309)